# ImportError: cannot import name 'ProductDetails' from 'pages.views'

Tags: python, django, pytest

I have written test case for views for details page. Here is below code I have written, When I am running Pytest in terminal it raising these error. My project structure is as below

```
 path('ProductDetails/<int:id>', views.onClickSearch.ProductDetails, name='ProductDetails'),
```

```
class onClickSearch():

    def ProductDetails(request, id):
        try:
            email = request.session.get('email')
            proddtls = vk_master_table.objects.filter(id=id).first()
            if proddtls:
                banners = Extras().bestDeals_cat(proddtls.category_desc)

        # print(banners.product_name)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            return render(request, "ProductDetails.html", {'error': error, 'form': HomeForm(),
                                                           'time': settings.SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT,
                                                           'name': first_last_initial(email),
                                                           'msg_count': msg_count_cl(email),
                                                           'fullname': fullname(email), 'ProductDetails': proddtls,
                                                           'signinForm': SigninForm(), 'signupForm': CustomerForm()})
        return render(request, "ProductDetails.html", {'ProductDetails': proddtls, 'fbanners': banners,
                                                       'form': HomeForm(), 'signinForm': SigninForm(),
                                                       'name': first_last_initial(email),
                                                       'msg_count': msg_count_cl(email),
                                                       'fullname': fullname(email),
                                                       'time': settings.SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT,
                                                       'signupForm': CustomerForm()})
```

```
from django.test import RequestFactory
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from pages.models import vk_customer
from mixer.backend.django import mixer
import pytest
    
from pages.views import ProductDetails
    
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestViews:
    
    def test_product_detail_authenticated(self):
        mixer.blend('pages.vk_master_table')
        path = reverse('detail', kwargs={'pk': 1516})
        request = RequestFactory().get(path)
        request.user = mixer.blend(vk_customer)
    
        response = ProductDetails(request, pk=1516)
        print(response)
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

This the error i am getting.....

```
    ____________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting pages/tests/test_views.py ____________________________________________________________
    ImportError while importing test module 'H:\Project\mysite\pages\tests\test_views.py'.
    Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
    Traceback:
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    pages\tests\test_views.py:8: in <module>
        from pages.views import ProductDetails
    E   ImportError: cannot import name 'ProductDetails' from 'pages.views' (H:\Project\mysite\pages\views.py)
```

Please help me out to solve this error.

Thank you
~Salima

Comment: Do you have a view called `ProductDetails`? Could you post your views as well?

Comment: okay I am posting `ProductDetails` views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a class named  onClickSearch  with method  ProductDetails . So I can't import a method of a class. To use the method I need to import class.
So in place of importing  from pages.views import ProductDetails  in test_views.py did from pages.views import onClickSearch  & then use it's method as onClickSearch.

Answer (score -1):

This is my views.py of ProductDetails.

```
def ProductDetails(request, id):
    try:
        email = request.session.get('email')
        proddtls = vk_master_table.objects.filter(id=id).first()
        if proddtls:
            banners = Extras().bestDeals_cat(proddtls.category_desc)

    # print(banners.product_name)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return render(request, "ProductDetails.html", {'error': error, 'form': HomeForm(),
                                                       'time': settings.SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT,
                                                       'name': first_last_initial(email),
                                                       'msg_count': msg_count_cl(email),
                                                       'fullname': fullname(email), 'ProductDetails': proddtls,
                                                       'signinForm': SigninForm(), 'signupForm': CustomerForm()})
    return render(request, "ProductDetails.html", {'ProductDetails': proddtls, 'fbanners': banners,
                                                   'form': HomeForm(), 'signinForm': SigninForm(),
                                                   'name': first_last_initial(email),
                                                   'msg_count': msg_count_cl(email),
                                                   'fullname': fullname(email),
                                                   'time': settings.SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT,
                                                   'signupForm': CustomerForm()})
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your own question. Please delete this and add the extra info by editing your question instead.